# Asus Xonar SE in Ubuntu Studio 23.10

Tags: drivers, sound, asus, microphone, soundcard

A Very Linux article informed me (mis) that the Asus Xonar SE card was compatible with Linux.I bought this card, because with the current one, a Realtek, which is integrated with the motherboard, and I couldn't get any of my microphones to work.The Asus Xonar SE is also not compatible with Linux, and I can't get my Ubuntu Studio 23.10 to record sound from my microphone.Does anyone know how I can solve this.None of the answers posted in previous threads work, at least on my computer.